# Wiring an air conditioner blower motor in a Ford Mustang

Tags: motor, ac, dc, pwm, potentiometer

I am having some wiring issues with my vehicle following a fender bender. Everything on my air conditioner works as expected except for the blower motor. I can confirm it is a new blower with issues receiving power.

I had the thought to wire the blower to the battery using a circuit to control the blower speed by limiting the current delivered to the motor. The motor is rated to a 20 amperes peak at 12 volts. Would obviously be running off a 12 volt lead acid battery capable of outputting several times the current required to kill the blower. I'm not having any luck finding a PWM designed the operate in the required ranges.

Basically my question is whether anyone has any recommendations on how to set up such a circuit.

Comment: Just because a battery can deliver a couple of hundred amperes it doesn't mean your circuit (or motor or lamp) has to handle all of the current all the time.  Your motor is made for 12V.  It will draw an appropriate amount of current.  You don't have to protect it from having a couple of hundred amperes forced through it.  Reducing the speed by reducing the current is a legitimate thing to do, but there should already be a control in your car to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The older control circuits for blower motors used a rheostat (aka variable resistor) or a 4 or 5 position switch to vary the resistance.

They were designed to alter the field strength - which reduced the current the switch had to deal with.